# Combo select não funciona

Tags: javascript

Há dias tentando resolver este problema na listagem das subcategorias mas, sem sucesso. Alguma solução ? Não quer mostrar as subcategorias no select

OBS: No PHP fiz `return $subcategorias->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` quando peguei as subcategorias no banco

*Print*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Código*

```
$("select[name=categoria]").change(function(){
    $("select[name=subcategoria]").html('<option value="" selected="selected">Carregando...</option>');
    $.post(split[0] + "/combo/categoria", {
            categoria: $(this).val()
    }, function(retorno){
        $.each(retorno.subcategoria, function(i, val){
            var subcategoria = '<option value="'+retorno.subcategoria[i].subcategoria+'">'+retorno.subcategoria[i].subcategoria+'</option>';
            $("select[name=subcategoria]").html(subcategoria);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o seu retorno é uma lista de objetos:

```
[
  {subcategoria: "Artesanato"},  
  {subcategoria: "Esculturas"},
  {subcategoria: "Ferramentas"},
  {subcategoria: "Livros"}
];
```

Não faz sentido você interar sobre a propriedade `subcategoria`, pois ela só existe nos elementos pertencentes à lista, como você fez em:

```
$.each(retorno.subcategoria, function(i, val){
    var subcategoria = '<option value="'+retorno.subcategoria[i].subcategoria+'">'+retorno.subcategoria[i].subcategoria+'</option>';
    $("select[name=subcategoria]").html(subcategoria);
});
```

O correto é interrar sobre o próprio retorno e acessar a propriedade `subcategoria` do valor presente na lista:

```
$.each(retorno, function(i, val) {
// -----------^
    var subcategoria = '<option value="'+val.subcategoria+'">'+val.subcategoria+'</option>';
    // ----------------------------------^ --------------^ ----^ --------------^
    $("select[name=subcategoria]").append(subcategoria);
    // ----------------------------^
});
```

> **Nota**: Os comentários inseridos no código no formato `---^` indicam os pontos em que aconteceram as mudanças em relação ao código original e, por isso, merecem maior atenção.

Perceba também que é necessário substituir o método `html` pelo `append`, pois o primeiro sempre sobrescreve o valor atual e, se usado, apenas apareceria a última subcategoria da lista. De forma a aparecer todas, usa-se o método `append`, que apenas insere o novo valor ao final do valor atual.

#### Exemplo

```js
const RETORNO = '[{"subcategoria": "Artesanato"},{"subcategoria": "Esculturas"},{"subcategoria": "Ferramentas"},{"subcategoria": "Livros"}]';

$(() => {
  var list = $("#list");
  $.each(JSON.parse(RETORNO), (key, value) => {
  //-----^ Aqui você converte seu retorno, que é uma string, para objeto
    let option = "<li>" + value.subcategoria + "</li>";
    list.append(option);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: Exibe o seguinte erro no console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in [{"subcategoria":"Artesanato"},{"subcategoria":"Esculturas"},{"subcategoria":"Ferramentas e Materiais"},{"subcategoria":"Livros"},{"subcategoria":"Pinturas"},{"subcategoria":"Outros"}]

Comment: Provavelmente porque você não converteu o retorno para objeto.

Comment: Sou leigo ainda kkkk pode me dizer como faria isso?

Comment: Editei o exemplo que dei na resposta, colocando como pode fazer a conversão.

Comment: Perfeito =D Mas ao exibir as subcategorias, fica com o option "Carregando..." como selected hahahaha. Como posso tirar após o carregamento das subcategorias, para finalizar aqui com chave de ouro ? :)

Comment: Use o método `hide` do jQuery, mas isso deixarei por sua conta. Só olhar na documentação.

Comment: Obrigado pela paciência e ajuda, vlw :)